# Distinction between json decoding and objects in php

Tags: php, json, oop

If I send the message

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
     -d '{"name": "Bob", "age": 32}' \
     http://localhost:8000/user.php
```

while running `php -S localhost:8000` on the directory containing `user.php`:

```
<?php
    class User {
        public $name, $age;
        function __construct($name, $age) {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->age = $age;
        }
    }

    $user1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $user2 = new User("Bob", 32);
?>
```

Is there any distinction between $user1 and $user2? If yes, how can I decode the message directly into an instance of class User? If no, does this mean that class User is altogether redundant in the sample above?

Docs:

- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, to get an object out of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), you need to pass `false` as the second argument, otherwise the result (what you're currently getting) is an associative array. Note `false` is the default for the second argument, so you can simply omit it here.

Assuming you don't pass `true` for the second argument to `json_decode`, `$user1` in your example is an instance of [`stdClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php), whereas `$user2` is an instance of `User`, so the instances are of different classes.

If you want to make the input into a `User` instance you could do

```
$rawUser = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$user1   = new User($rawUser->name, $rawUser->age);
```

Another way might be a `static` factory method

```
class User {
    public $name, $age;
    function __construct($name, $age) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

   static public function fromRaw(stdClass $rawUser) {
       $newUser = new self();
       $newUser->name = $rawUser->name;
       $newUser->age  = $rawUser->age;

       return $newUser;
   }
}
```

then you could revise the first example to

```
$rawUser = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$user1   = User::fromRaw($rawUser);
```

Comment: Instead of `new User();`, you shouls use `new self();`. Try it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ee4edf53a46357dc5ba446febd220f0199dd2f8

Comment: @quickshiftin  Sounds good, with almost perfect clarity! But one point remains: It seems wasteful to get `json_decode` to first construct an instance of `stdClass`, only to then keep it for just an instant before constructing the object we really want. Yet short of parsing the string returned by file_get_contents myself, that's just good enough. Could you opine?

Comment: @Calif the problem is JSON is not a native format to php. If you use [serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) instead, you can pass a instance of a class as a string, then when you call [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) you'll have the instance immediately available without the intermediate steps from the JSON approach.